# Android Studio: Failed to create MD5 HashFile

Tags: java, android, android-studio, md5

I am creating a simple android application... I ran into some kind of trouble when I updated gradle when I launched Android Studio and it prompted me too.

Upon the update completing I receive the following error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Failed to create MD5 hash for file '/Users/damenTomassi/AndroidStudioProjects/AstraeaDemo/app/src/main/res/libs/gson-2.3.1.jar'.

I used to have the GSON library in my project, however I no longer needed it so I removed it...

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You didn't delete the jar file?

Comment: @cricket_007 Hello, I did delete the Jar file!

Comment: remove entry from gradle file.

Comment: And you have since done a Gradle clean task?

Comment: @cricket_007 By Gradle clean task do you mean deleting the .gradle file? This is what I have attempted so far... I must apologize, I am new to android development and Android Studio.

Comment: @santoshgore Hello, thank you for your response! How do I remove the entry from the gradle file? I cannot find any suitable solutions on Google

Comment: Nope, I literally mean `gradle clean` (it's a command that you can run)

Comment: check your gradle file and remove entry from gradle file.rebuild your gradle

Comment: @cricket_007 Hello, I attempted that just now, and I still have the same results. Any other suggestions? Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: You could remove the `compile fileTree` line temporarily, then rebuild. I generally recommend not using jar files anyway unless necessary

Comment: @santoshgore hello, I do not see this file in the directory, I also rebuilt it and still the same results. Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: Just try to rebuild project after disabling instant run.

Comment: @cricket_007 hello, where would I find this line of code? At the time I had plans to use it, however now I do not require any longer so I decided to remove it!

Comment: In the `build.gradle` that manages your app in the dependencies section

Comment: Hello @pRaNaY - I just attempted to do this, I am still receiving the same error! Thank you!

Comment: use https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/index.html url to see gradle file location.

Comment: @cricket_007 This is the only thing in the build.gradle section:dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }

Comment: There's two gradle files with the same name

Comment: Hello @cricket_007 I found the proper one and commented out the line regarding gson, this fixed the error however created a new one! The symbol "R" can not be found now!

Comment: Hello all, I have solved the problem by copying all of the code and xml files to a new project! Thank You!

Comment: I just created new project with the files copying after wasting 7-8 hours on this issue

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this

Step 1:
       **Remove** this **compile files('lib/gson-2.3.1.jar')** from Your **build.gradle** File

Step 2:
        **Build-> Clean Project**

Comment: Hello, In my build.gradle file there is only this:  dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }

Comment: @DamenTomassi That's Project Level Gradle File..!!!  Check the App Level Gradle File Under the App Folder

Comment: @RAJESHKUMARARUMUGAM This resolved the error, HOWEVER now my main activity will not compile and I get the message "Can not resolve Symbol R" for code such as this: adTitleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.adTitle);
        adContentTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.adDetail);

Comment: @DamenTomassi Try **File->Invalidate Caches/Restart** and then Click **Invalidate Caches/Restart**

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes...!! I have Seen but it's not clear for him

Comment: @RAJESHKUMARARUMUGAM I just tried this option, and unfortunately the same thing happens... any other suggestions? Thank you for all of your help so far! It really means a lot!

Comment: It's my Pleasure..!! Try  Build->Rebuild Project

Comment: @RAJESHKUMARARUMUGAM unfortunately this does not work either!

Comment: Have You Restarted the Android Studio..?

Comment: @RAJESHKUMARARUMUGAM I just tried that and my entire computer as well and it did not work:( I do not know why this happened, I was having absolutely no issues yesterday!

Comment: Once It Happened for me too.Instead of sticking with this, Better You may Create a New Project and Simply Copy&Paste the Same Java Files and Xml Files to the new One.

Comment: @RAJESHKUMARARUMUGAM Hello, I just did this and it solved the problem! Thank you for all of the help! I do not know why this happened, perhaps I will consult the developer for additional guidance to avoid this problem in the future!

Comment: @RAJESHKUMARARUMUGAM Thank You!

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007

Answer (score 1):

I could solve this issue by deselecting Instant Run. 
You can do this by going to

`File`**->**`settings`**->**`build,execution,deplyment`**->** `deselect instant run`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue today, and after wasting an hour trying everything else mentioned I updated my Android Studio to the latest release and got a different error message that the jar file did not exist. Checking my project this error was correct, I had,

```
compile files('libs/activation.jar')
compile files('libs/mail.jar')
compile 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.5.5'
compile 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.5.5'
```

But did not have a file, libs/activation.jar, for some reason this use to work fine, but stopped working today. I change it to just,

```
compile 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.5.5'
compile 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.5.5'
```

and my build now works again. Odd, but I did try commenting out those lines before, but still got the error, so maybe updating Studio helped too, or I needed to do a combination of the above.

Anyway problem solved and check that your jars actually existing in the libs directory.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a transient issue in gradle. I fixed it by killing the running gradle daemons (`pkill -f gradle`) and rebuilding.