# After deleting jar file from lib getting error from gradle while building project

Tags: android, android-studio, jar

I have added a jar file inside app/libs folder. then right click and added jar file as library.The project builds perfectly. After that I have deleted the jar file from libs folder.

Now its showing a Failed to create MD5 hash for file.

using android studio - 2.3.1

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43221781/3253038) solution but didn't find anything inside my gradle file.

[image]

Comment: Check if it is still there in your project structure

Comment: don't know where to check. I am a new user of android studio.

Comment: Android studio shows more than 1 gradle file. Check the other one.

Comment: any screenshot would be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you can see the above picture in Android Studio this would be your project structure. Check the Dependency and see if the Jar is still available in the Project