# failed to create MD5 hash for my BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

please survive me from this error suddenly happened in my BroadcastReceiver.
Failed to create MD5 hash for file!
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
please do not refer me to 
[Android Studio: Failed to create MD5 HashFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43221538/android-studio-failed-to-create-md5-hashfile), this didn't solve my problem.
and this is my BroadcastReceiver.

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(MyBroadcastReceiver.class.getSimpleName(), "Service Stops!");
        Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, DbInsertService.class);
    context.startService(startServiceIntent);
 }
}
```

Comment: did you make any version changes in your gradle ?

Comment: no I didn't. @mrid

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild

Comment: @mrid I did so for many times. It didn't make a sound!

Answer (score 0):

I've been fighting with this issue and noticed that notifications about "suspicious apps" from Windows Defender (I'm using Windows 10) appear each time I'm trying to build an app. 
I've disabled Windows defender and everything worked like a charm.